# Where in the file system are iPhoto pictures located?

Tags: photos.app, filesystem

I have a friend who's hard drive died on their Mac Mini. I have removed the hard drive and placed it in external drive enclosure. I have a trick that may give me 5-10 good minutes with the drive before it spins it last spin, and I intend to use that time (if I can) to get a few files from the drive.

After talking with the friend, the most important data to them are photos that were stored in iPhotos in one of the profiles. Given that I will have at best only a few minutes with the drive, I want to know exactly where on the file system to look for this data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## iPhoto Photos Location

iPhoto stores photos and meta-data in the user's home folder:

**~/Pictures/iPhoto Library**

Within this folder, the original photos are stored at:

**~/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Masters**

### Bulk Copy with rsync

If the user name was `friend`, the `rsync` [command to copy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117465/fastest-and-safest-way-to-copy-massive-data-from-one-external-drive-to-another) all the original photos to the local desktop would be:

`rsync -ra '/Volumes/MacMini/Users/friend/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Masters' ~/Desktop`

Comment: Thanks. This definitely would have worked. Sadly, I was only able to buy about 20s of time with the drive... barely long enough to even recognize it's plugged in. No data this time :(