# Copy not possible from ssd to another ssd

Tags: macos, disk-utility

We want to move 30GB of data located on a 128GB ssd to another 120gb ssd. This is not possible as disk utility says that /dev/disk2s2 doesn't have enough space.

The data we want to copy is os x itself, and some programs used in the store.

Can this be solved by partitioning the 128gb ssd and than copy the partition? Or is the a command line way to achieve this?

**update**
At this time, we partitioned the 128ssd. We just started copying, fingers crossed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remote Synchronisation: `rsync`

Consider using OS X's **Terminal.app** and included `rsync` command line tool to safely copy the data:

```
sudo rsync -vaE --progress /Volumes/SourceName /Volumes/DestinationName
```

See [Fastest and safest way to copy massive data from one external drive to another](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117465/fastest-and-safest-way-to-copy-massive-data-from-one-external-drive-to-another/) for how this command works and what each section means.