# copyfile errors and dot files using rsync

Tags: macos, backup, error, file-transfer, rsync

I read @SwisherSweet's question of the [fastest and safest way to copy massive data from one external drive to another](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117465/fastest-and-safest-way-to-copy-massive-data-from-one-external-drive-to-another), along with @GrahamMiln's [excellent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117469/46045).

I'm in a similar situation where I want to copy data from a Firewire 800 connected external hd to Drobo 5N, which is connected to the router that the iMac is connected to:
ExternalHd — iMac — Router — Drobo5N

I executed the command (`sudo rsync -vaE --progress /Volumes/SourceName /Volumes/DestinationName`) and it works for some part, but on occasion I get the following error (I inserted some line breaks for better readability):

```
Boxx:~ Alex$ sudo rsync -vaE --progress /Volumes/ExternalHd/path/to/MyDirectory /Volumes/Drobo5N/path/to/

building file list ... 
6 files to consider

._MyDirectory
        1104 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=5/6)

MyDirectory/._file1.dmg
        1430 100%   34.06kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=3/6)

MyDirectory/._file2.dmg
        1430 100%   27.38kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=2/6)

copyfile(.._MyDirectory.drJHX3,./MyDirectory, COPYFILE_UNPACK) failed:45
copyfile(MyDirectory/.._file1.dmg.PQTcsU,MyDirectory/file1.dmg, COPYFILE_UNPACK) failed:45
rsync: rename "/Volumes/Drobo5N/path/to/MyDirectory/.._file1.dmg.PQTcsU" -> "MyDirectory/._file1.dmg": No such file or directory (2)
copyfile(MyDirectory/.._file2.dmg.gx7VTP,MyDirectory/file2.dmg, COPYFILE_UNPACK) failed:45
rsync: rename "/Volumes/Drobo5N/path/to/MyDirectory/.._file2.dmg.gx7VTP" -> "MyDirectory/._file2.dmg": No such file or directory (2)

sent 4369 bytes  received 86 bytes  8910.00 bytes/sec
total size is 48176733  speedup is 10814.08

rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
```

**Some questions:**

1. Why do I get these `copyfile(...) failed:45` errors?
   I found the [source code for copyfile.c](http://opensource.apple.com//source/copyfile/copyfile-42/copyfile.c), but could not find out what triggers the error. In there it says about COPYFILE_UNPACK:

   > COPYFILE_UNPACK is the undoing of COPYFILE_PACK, obviously.
   >   The goal there is to take an Apple Double file, and turn it
   >   into a normal file (with data fork, resource fork, modes,
   >   extended attributes, ACLs, etc.).

   My error message says something about `COPYFILE_UNPACK`, but what
   does it mean and how can I fix the error?
2. Why does the `rsync` command create the dot file like `._file1.dmg`?
    When `rsync` completes successfully I still see the dot file in the synced destination directory (/Volumes/Drobo5N/path/to/) in addition to the actual synced file. Why is that?
3. Why does `rsync` create extensions like `.drJHX3`? Is that a temp name?

---

<sup>P.S.: Sorry if this has been asked elsewhere. I've search for this error using rsync, but couldn't surface any.</sup>

Comment: Apple's rsync is old so I would find a more uptodate one especially with metadata issues. Also what format are the drives

Comment: Are you saying the copyfile errors are due to metadata issues?With "format" do you mean file system? I will need to look the  up when I'm back at my desk… Should I be surprised if the file system is HFS+ because the resource-/metadata-fork is stored as a separate file?

Comment: @Mark Would you recommend updating via [MacPorts](https://guide.macports.org/)

Comment: @graham-miln Since you gave the winning answer for the question that triggered my question here, I was wondering if you have some input, if you like.

Comment: Error 45 is defined in `/usr/include/sys/errno.h`- `#define ENOTSUP  45  /* Operation not supported */`

Comment: I too see this a lot. I believe it has something to do with transferring data from HFS+ to non-HFS+ file system, that don't support macOS file system features.

Answer (score 4):

I was using the -E option to copy alias files on macOS (as without -E option alias files copy as executable files). The -E Options worked for copying the Alias files, but caused the same error as here on other files (`COPYFILE_UNPACK failed:45`). Therefore appears error is probably caused by using -E option in macOS.

Fortunately using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and running `brew install rsync` to install a more recent version of `rsync` fixed the problem.

Source: https://bayton.org/2018/07/how-to-update-rsync-on-mac-os-high-sierra/

Answer (score 2):

Copyfile is responsible for splitting a HFS+ file into two files. The  data fork- `file` and a metadata fork- `._file`. That happens when you use the `-E` option with the Apple supplied `rsync`. I have no idea why it is failing. `rsync` does create temporary files and then moves them into place.