# How do I transfer files fast over two network shares?

Tags: mac, smb, nas

I have two shares (A, B) on the same volume on a synology NAS. I'm have the two shares mounted in finder, but when copying or moving files it takes forever, even with SMB3 on. I can of course use Synology's file browser which takes seconds, but the issue is that I can't easly open and preview files - I would like to use Finder if possible or at least an app for Mac that would allow me to open the files.

Comment: Instead of using Finder for the transfer, use the Terminal commands `cp` or `mv`. Using Finder adds lots of overhead to the transfers, whilst `cp` and `mv` are fast, and can handle transferring folder structures and other cool stuff.  You might also want to consider using `rsync`, which is [discussed here at AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117465/fastest-and-safest-way-to-copy-massive-data-from-one-external-drive-to-another).

Comment: So you are copying a file from NAS Share "A" to NAS share "B" and you are wondering why it is slower than moving a file logged into the NAS user interface? It's because you are transferring the file from "A" to "B" VIA the Mac. The Mac is doing the copy operation so it goes from "A" to the Mac and then to "B" effectively two slow *NETWORK* copy operations. It will **always** be slow that way.

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 2):

Moving files from one share on a host to another share on the *same* host will always be faster when initiated from the host itself, and will *always* be slow when transferred from the host to a client (and back).  Regardless of whether you use Finder, or `mv` or `cp` or Carbon Copy Cloner, if the data has to traverse the network, it will be orders of magnitude slower.

There are some technologies that allow a copy or duplicate command on the *same* share to be initiated by a client and performed server-side instead of copying the whole file down to the client and then back.  I believe SMB supports this, but it it won't work across *different* shares, even if they're on the same host.

Long story short, your network will always be the bottleneck compared to the disk controller's native speed (~88MBps for Gigabit Ethernet vs. 200-600MBps for SATA). If you're running 100Base-T on your network instead of Gigabit, you'll be 10x slower than that (8MBps).

To (pre)view anything on the Mac, you'll always have to transfer it (or enough of it) to the Mac over the network.  For large items, I'd recommend using the Synology's interface to move or copy items between the different shares.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) as a rsync gui makes better use of the bandwidth available compared to copying using the Finder's drag and drop. If you don't want to use the NAS interface, that's the only way to maximize the transfer rate.

I will also suggest using [Menumeters](https://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/MenuMetersElCapitan) to measure your network speeds, and use a wired Ethernet connection instead of Wifi if this is applicable.

Comment: The value of AD (and other SE sites) comes from answers which go beyond mere product recommendations. It‘s fine to recommend tools, but wouldn’t it be even more helpful if an answer also explains (to the OP and any future visitor) how a tool you use and know can be used in the context of the question?

Comment: @historystamp It‘s fine to propose different policies, please raise a question on the meta site for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you need but you may be able to use either the 'scp' command for remote transfers or the 'cp' command for local transfers.

```
cp /Volume/share/path1/* /Volume/share/path2
```

Use * to copy the entire contents of the folder.