# Is there a way to prevent my Mac from sleeping during a file copy?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, power-management

I'm copying a lot of files (over 700 GB) and it takes hours to complete. Is there a way to keep the Mac from sleeping before the copy process completes? I don't want to sit by the computer and moving my mouse from time to time.

I tried to set my Energy Saver settings as:

[image: Energy Saver settings showing sleep disabled]

But sometimes it still dies. So currently, I have to sit by the laptop and wait.

Comment: I do things like this often and the copy continues even though the computer puts the screen into sleep, but the processor continues the copy. A copy even over-rides the automatic shutdown/reboot that I have set for 1AM...

Comment: "dies" or goes to sleep?

Comment: How do you copy those files? Command line or Finder?

Answer (score 40):

## `caffeinate rsync`

Consider using the command line tool `rsync` to [safely copy large amounts of data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117469/1860) on your Mac. Prefix the command with [`caffeinate`](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/caffeinate.html) to keep your Mac awake during the copy.

The Terminal.app command will look something like:

```
 sudo caffeinate rsync -vaE --progress /Volumes/SourceName /Volumes/DestinationName
```

`rsync` has the benefit of being able to resume failed or interrupted copies.

If the copy has already begun, run `caffeinate` with the flag `-t <seconds>` for a specific duration or `-w <pid>` for the life time of a specific process.

Comment: `rsync` by itself is excellent advice. There are very few cases when operating interactively where `cp` should be used instead of `rsync`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the freely available app "Amphetamine" from the Mac App Store to keep the Mac awake:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12

Another similarly free app is "Jiggler":

http://www.sticksoftware.com/software/Jiggler.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120090/discussion-on-answer-by-jksoegaard-is-there-a-way-to-prevent-my-mac-from-sleepin).

Answer (score 9):

If you always remain on AC power during the copy and your above *Energy Saver* settings are indeed accurate, then I can think of no reason why your system would enter idle sleep unless there is some process that specifically forces a sleep at some point. You can check for sleep entry & causes by examining the power management log:

```
$ pmset -g log
```

In any case, in order to prevent the system from going to sleep you can acquire a power management assertion with the use of `caffeinate(8)`, which is built in to macOS and accessible via *Terminal*:

```
$ caffeinate
```

The system will not sleep until you exit (via <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>).

From your description, I suspect that you might *not* actually be on AC power the whole time and instead are running off the battery. Please double check this first.

Comment: Was thinking the same thing. I have my Mac Pro settings similar while copying large files and my Mac always seems to complete the tasks. Although, these commands seem like a great alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of options already here, but just to complete the set…

System Prefs > Desktop & Screen Saver > Screen Saver > Hot Corners…

Choose a corner to Disable Screen Saver & just push your cursor hard into that corner when you want it to stay awake.

I've never actually tried this on a laptop, but I've been using it successfully on Mac Pros for over a decade.

Comment: This is the way I always do it, because I didn't know about this `caffeinate` thing.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me too, I solved by playing audio/video when I don't want to my laptop go to sleep.

Another way use auto click software like
http://www.murgaa.com/auto-clicker-mac/

Comment: This is exactly what my child has to do on her school-issued Chromebook to keep it from sleeping during breaks because the managed-device controls don't allow disabling the ridiculously short inactivity lock or installing custom applications. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
caffeinate
```

And then CTRL + SHIFT + ESC

When your monitor should be off, but the computer continues to work

Answer (score 0):

You can force your laptop to never sleep entirely in  terminal:
Display global power settings:
 `pmset -g`

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 proximitywake        1
 standby              1
 standbydelaylow      10800
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 womp                 0
 displaysleep         10
 networkoversleep     0
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by sharingd)
 tcpkeepalive         1
 halfdim              1
 acwake               0
 disksleep            10
```

Then:
 To stop sleep entirely:
`sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1`
To revert, allowing sleep again:
`sudo pmset -a disablesleep 0`