how to transfer Time machine data from NAS to USB drive so that it can be restored from?
I backed up my old mac mini (2011) using Time machine to a NAS over SMB. Now I'd like to restore the mini from the backup, however the SMB mount is not accessible from the Recovery mode (at least on OS X Lion, as also referenced on Mounting SMB network share from Mavericks recovery mode) and I cannot easily reconfigure the NAS share to use AFP.
Nevertheless, I can login into the NAS using SSH and I can see the files:
nas% ls /mnt/uloziste/macbackup/mini/vladak/
.apdisk                           .DS_Store                         Vladimir’s Mac mini.sparsebundle/ 
nas% ls /mnt/uloziste/macbackup/mini/vladak/Vladimir’s\ Mac\ mini.sparsebundle/
bands                       com.apple.TimeMachine.Results.plist     Info.plist
com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.bckup       com.apple.TimeMachine.SnapshotHistory.plist token
com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist       Info.bckup

How do I transfer these files to a USB drive (formatted as Mac OS Extended) so that the Recovery mode will recognize it as a Time machine drive and will be able to recover from it ?

This sounds like you came up with your own process that mimics Time Machine.  The NAS doesn't just advertise itself as a Time Machine target?

The TIme machine share was set up using standard procedure, at least for TrueNAS, as per https://www.truenas.com/docs/scale/scaletutorials/shares/smb/setupbasictimemachinesmbshare/. The NAS does advertises itself as a Time machine target, however only over SMB which is not available in the Recovery mode.

If the NAS advertises itself as a TM target, what is stopping you from restoring from it?  You shouldn't need to mount it out-of-band.

The share is SMB only and the OS X Recovery mode in Lion cannot mount SMB it seems (see the link in problem description).

What OS was making the backups, out of curiosity?  What about reinstalling the OS, then  using Migration Assistant from the backup?

macOS High Sierra. The Recovery mode is Lion. I tried installing the Lion from from the recovery mode however that failed for some reason.

Yeah, I think I'd concentrate on getting a usable OS onto the Mini, then just using Migration Assistant to recover the data.  Lion is way old relative to HS.  I don't know how many of the old make-a-bootable-USB tools that understand HS still work on a more modern OS.  I have a bootable HS, I have one of all the OS archived away.

Format USB drive as macOS Extended (Journaled) and then just copy the files from the NAS SMB share to a local drive and the Recovery mode restore pane will discover it. It does not even had to be restarted.
The copying itself can be done e.g. using the following command from the Terminal (available in the Utilities in the Recovery mode), although any other method will likely work (e.g. using Finder or rsync or such), however in my case I was limited by the fact that the only Apple machine in the household was broken and need to be restored, so I had to use whatever the Recovery mode had to offer. In this case it assumes the SSH public key authentication was set up prior to that, however one can also use password based authentication, if one remembers the password to the NAS, that is):
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i id_rsa vladak@nas \
    "cd /mnt/uloziste/macbackup/mini/vladak/; tar cf - ." | \
    tar -C /Volumes/T7 -xvf -

The command runs tar to create a data stream (not necessarily compressing) from the files on the NAS and the SSH client will pass that stream to a local tar instance which will create the files.
The StrictHostKeyChecking=no SSH option was used because root's home directory in Recovery mode is not writable, so the SSH client would ask for key fingerprint verification on rekeying which happens for longer data transfers such as this one and it would require user interaction to repeatedly reconfirm the key.
The /Volumes/T7 is where a USB SSD drive was mounted to, formatted using MacOS Extended (Journaled).
While investigating the Time machine disk format, I came across a really nice source on https://tommyang.github.io/pondini.org/TM/Works3.html
The copying process above will spend most of the time transferring all the bands files.

I suggest you to avoid Finder and tar because you will lose files and attributes with this 2 tools.

Rather use rsync which will preserve your full filesystem integrity.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117469/22003
